# Can a non-EU citizen work in one EU country and reside in another?

Tags: working-visas, eu, resident-permit

I am a non-EU citizen software developer, which means I should be considered highly skilled migrant practically everywhere in the EU.

I want to move to Czech Republic (my girlfriend lives there as a non-EU student/researcher), but there are more jobs (and more good jobs) for me in, for example Germany or The Netherlands. Some of these companies allow working remote, so I was wondering if it is legally possible for me to work for, let's say, German company (and thus acquire a German working permit) and reside in Czech Republic?

Comment: @DannyBeckett: [O RLY?](https://goo.gl/maps/TUHfM)  (Also, he/she did mention working remote.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh. That's funny. When I put it into Google Maps, it said 5.5 hours each way :S

Comment: @Zemljoradnik how did it go for you? I am in exactly same spot right now, however I reside in Germany and got a remote job offer in Italy.

Comment: @roko it didn't, I found a job in Czech Republic in the end. Not saying it's not possible, I just didn't even try in the end because I got a good offer here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd keep it simple. And either..

1) Apply for an EU Blue Card (gives most advantages)

2) Start your own company (allows lots of geographic flexibility for assignments)

The EU Blue Card gives you full flexibility in terms of mobility (not needing to re-apply for each country for work permits), whereas starting your own company lets you sidestep the labour market entirely and simply work where you want.

In general, receiving a residency permit in one Schengen country allows permit-holders a [certain amount of mobility](http://ec.europa.eu/immigration/tab1.do?subSec=30), but you are still bound by national laws.

> To move from one Schengen area country to another for more than three months, you will need a long-term visa and/or a permit for that country. If you wish to work, study or join your family in the second country, you may have to fulfil more national conditions. To travel to a country that is not in the borderless Schengen area, you must get a separate national visa and meet all the necessary conditions.

As a skilled knowledge worker, you in principle qualify for an [EU Blue Card](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:155:0017:0029:EN:PDF). The linked PDF explains all the various rights/privileges it offers you - including affirmed ease of mobility within EU member states. It is the most straightforward way to achieve your aim (to live in one country and be directly employed in another, with the right to choose yet another in the future).

The details for work permits do vary from country to country, making a Blue Card a useful thing to have. Note that UK, Ireland and Denmark do **not** participate in the Blue Card scheme.

Going through the front door for German work permits, which [assume residency](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Infoservice/FAQ/ArbeitLebenDeutschland/01-Arbeitsmoeglichkeiten.html?nn=383016) can make it easier for some companies to sponsor you. [Also here](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/EinreiseUndAufenthalt/LernenUndArbeiten/ArbeiteninD_node.html#doc371012bodyText1) more information in German. Work permit regulations usually require substantial effort/commitment from employers which can be a barrier. This could also mean having an official residence in Germany (or wherever), which could also increase your costs.

If you don't want to go the route of an EU Blue Card, and don't want to set yourself up as an official resident of Germany/NL, then start your own business and sell your services to companies that way - no need for complex social security tax constructions, etc. [Here](http://www.czechinvest.org/data/files/visas-en-2010-1050-en.pdf) is an English-language overview of the requirements for setting up a business in CZ in relation to residency permits, etc. And here's one for [NL](https://www.ind.nl/Documents/FAQ%20Regeling%20buitenlandse%20investeerder%2020140401.pdf). Be aware that different criteria regarding size of investment and/or number of jobs created may be applied.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I will read all the documents you linked, and get back with further questions if I have them. :)

Comment: `not needing to re-apply for each country for work permits` is not correct. But you explained more in later. If one is moving to another EU state, the one has to apply again for staying longer than 3 months within 6 months. I'm in a similar situation and I wanted to give heads up. I have German EU Blue Card for 26 months and I'll move to Austria while I'm keeping my job in Germany. I have to re-apply to EU Blue card in Austria. That's what government offices say.