# What does a non-EU citizen (German residence permit holder) require to live in the Netherlands?

Tags: resident-permit, netherlands

I am a non-EU citizen and work for a German company. We currently have a project in the Netherlands. I have a residence permit for Germany, and I would now like to get a BSN for the Netherlands, as I would be living there for extended periods. Am I eligible, or do I need to get a Dutch work permit? Mind you, I am employed in Germany and not the Netherlands. My passport is Australian.

Comment: Why do you need BSN? You are legally staying in EU and have German bank account for receiving money. Unless you changing your employer I don't see much reason to get Dutch work permit.

Comment: Please look at the related questions in the sidebar (hint: those already appear when you type a question), especially [this one](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2831/can-a-non-eu-citizen-work-in-one-eu-country-and-reside-in-another?rq=1)

Comment: @JanDoggen I looked and I don't see the connection.

Comment: De facto you can live in the Netherlands permit-free for as long as you want as detection is nigh impossible. But you won't be able to get any Dutch documents.

Comment: @JonathanReez a resident who has acquired long-term residence status in an EU country other than the UK, Ireland, or Denmark may relocate to another such country, so your comment is incorrect if OP is a long-term resident.

Comment: @phoog practically speaking EU permanent residents don't have it much easier: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9400/what-documents-are-needed-for-an-eu-permanent-resident-to-work-in-germany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *live* in the Netherlands, you almost certainly need a Dutch work and residence permit (the one exception that comes to mind is posted work but that's apparently not your status). The fact you are employed by a German company in Germany only makes formalities more complex but does not in itself exempt you from this basic requirement, which stems from the objective fact that you are residing there.

You can get a BSN has a non-resident but that's moot, even if you somehow managed to live in the Netherlands without one (which would make interaction with all public services difficult), you would still need a residence permit.

Comment: Does the free movement of services have no bearing on this? [Directive 2003/109/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=LEGISSUM:l23034) certainly would, if OP qualifies.